# Write Binary file from char buffer on linux

Tags: c++, linux, binary, buffer, raw

So i am new to linux programming on C++ and i am trying to write the contents of a binary file (.dll, .exe etc) to a .txt to test and see the results of the operation, the code works and writes the .txt file and some of the binary into it, but when i open the .txt file there is not the full binary writed inside and the problem is due invalid unicode from far i know.

**Here is a screenshot for better understanding:**

[Click here to see image from stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E14wD.png)

or

**Text Output when open the .txt file:**

```
MZ\90\00\00\00\00\00
```

**And here is the code i am using (reproducible example):**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

std::vector<char> buffer;

bool read_file(std::string name, std::vector<char>& out) 
{
  std::ifstream file(name.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

  if (!file.good()) 
  {
    return false;
  }

  file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  const size_t size = file.tellg();
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  out.resize(size);
  file.read(out.data(), size);
  file.close();

  return true;
}

void write_text_to_log_file(char* text)
{
    std::ofstream log_file("log_file.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app );
    log_file.write(text, sizeof(text));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    read_file("bin.dll", buffer);
    printf("Image Array: %s\r\n", buffer.data());
    printf("Image Size: %zu\r\n", buffer.size());
    write_text_to_log_file(buffer.data());
}
```

Any help is apreciated, i am trying to do exactly the same than file_get_contents of php and whit the raw binary buffer write the file, for example write the raw binary to .dll format .exe, .png etc etc.

Comment: If the screenshot contains text, then please [edit] your question to include the text copy-pasted *as text*.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I already fixed the image.

Comment: `sizeof(text)` is wrong, it will give you the size of the pointer, not the data it points at.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, sizeof is working perfectly it says the size of the pointer is 8704 and file size is 8,7kb.

Comment: @MovEax: That is not correct.  The `printf` in `main` prints `buffer.size()` whereas `write_text_to_log_file` calls `sizeof(text)`, try passing `const std::vector<char>&` instead of `char*` to `write_text_to_log_file`, then call `log_file.write(text.data(), text.size())`

Comment: You are mistaken. `sizeof` is not the same thing as `size`.

Comment: Solved by size, you guys was correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
log_file.write(text, sizeof(text));
```

`sizeof` is a ***compile time constant*** that gives you the size ***of the object***.  `text` is a `char *`, so this gives you a grand total of 4 or 8, depending on whether you compiled a 32bit or a 64bit binary. It doesn't matter whether `text` points to just a few bytes, or the entire contents of "Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows". This `sizeof` will always produce either a 4 or an 8 for you, no matter what's in `text`.

You need to pass an additional parameter here that comes from the `buffer.size()` of the `std::vector` where the data is stored, and use that here. `sizeof()` is ***not*** the same thing as a method of `std::vector` that's called "`size`".